# How to SQLite Query with constraint in xamarin forms cross platform C#?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I am working on this pet project in Xamarin.Forms cross platform. I am having difficulty running a query in SQLite using constraint.  I am able to list all the elements stored on the table. However, I am unable to query the table for all the jobs with the same AccountNumber. I've searched everywhere but i can't find the answer. Can anyone provide a working method that would help please and thank you in advance.

```
public SearchPage()
{
        InitializeComponent();

        _connection = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteDb>   ().GetConnection();
}

private SQLiteAsyncConnection _connection;
private ObservableCollection<Job> _jobs;

public class NewJobTable
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string JobID { get; set; }

    public long AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public int JobNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCompleted { get; set; }
}

protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    await _connection.CreateTableAsync<Job>();

    var jobs = await _connection.Table<Job>().ToListAsync();

    _jobs = new ObservableCollection<Job>(jobs);

    JobListView.ItemsSource = _jobs;

    base.OnAppearing();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add filering (`Where`) on AccountNumber

```
 var jobsWithSameAccountNumber = await _connection.Table<Job>()
                                  .Where(job => job.AccountNumber == accountNumberToCheck)
                                  .ToListAsync()
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you so much Milen